# The state of not progressing

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives, synonyms

What is the state of not progressing called? Going in circles. When the person is not progressing despite the active trying.

Comment: There are many expressions which could fit. Could you provide a little more context? For example is this person *trying* to climb out debt? Does he have a secret ambition? Has be been stuck on a problem for a long time?

Comment: One option is _stasis_, which can refer to (among other things) "a state of static balance or equilibrium: stagnation" or to "a state or period of stability during which little or no evolutionary change in a lineage occurs."

Comment: The question risks getting closed. Context means to give a situation, not to expand the meaning of "going round in circles". You could say: dead-end, standstill, blocked, deadlock, stalemate, static, hasn't moved/budged an inch, etc. and they would all fit.

Comment: **Trapped**: placed in a restricted position without consent and with no clear or easy means of escape (not voluntarily). As in "trapped in a dead-end job".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "stagnation" fits nicely.

[stagnate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stagnate) - *verb* - cease developing; become inactive or dull

[stagnant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stagnant) - *adjective* - showing no activity; dull and sluggish

Typically stagnation is used to refer to a lack of movement or development, rather than futile movement "in circles."

Your question brings to mind an idiom my mother used to say rather often: ["beating around the bush"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+around+the+bush) which means to stall or waste time.

You might also use "languishing" to describe the state of not progressing.

[Languish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/languish) - *verb* - fail to make progress or be successful

Answer (score 1):

I remember a colleague complaining that he was 'vegetating' in his job.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context

> - stalled
> - idling
> - treading water
> - dead in the water
> - marking time
> - biding time